# laravel render controller in blade template?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I want to render the Controller inside a blade template in Laravel, I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
{{ App::make('Subject')->show1(['id' => '150']) }}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you talking about child-actions (as they are called in .NET)? What is `Subject` in your code?

Comment: No , I just want show some news in the sidebar ,this news are shown by another controller , I wish that you understand ..

Comment: Is `id` a constant (always 150)? Or is `id` chosen by user?

Comment: it's variable ...  chosen by user ..

Comment: So, I think you have two possibilities: If there are (and will always be) just a few DB registers for this model, you can pass all of them as a collection to the view, before the user chooses; Or you can use ajax and call a controller function.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel you do that using a `view composer`.

You can test it by using this example in the `boot` method of your `AppServiceProvider`:

```
View::composer('*', function($view)
{
    $view->with('menuCategories', Category::all());
});
```

Now your `$menuCategories` will be available in all views.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/views#view-composers

Later on you can extract it to a dedicated service provider if you wish.